# C#/ WPF : Can't use MainWindows UI methods in "page"

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, animation, canvas

I don't know how to use my UI methods (animation menu with canvas and grid system) in my differents pages. The problem is, how can my page recognize XAML elements which are inside my MainWindows.xaml ? I don't know how to call MainWindows methods that use xaml elements in my page..

Ty

Comment: This makes no sense to me. Show some sample code and explain it

Comment: As @GlenThomas said I don't understand as well. To call MainWindow's methods you would use something like ((MainWindow)App.Current.MainWindow).MyMethod()